# Using GoogleMock to avoid dependencies when testing a Card and a CardCollection class

Tags: c++, testing, mocking, tdd, googlemock

I'm learning about mocking and am reasonably new to the concepts. For the sake of learning, I'm implementing a `Card` class and a `CardCollection` class which depends on the `Card`. Therefore I've created a `MockCard` for testing the `CardCollection`.

Here's the `Card.h`

```
    class ICard {
    protected:
        int rank_;
        std::string suit_;
    public:

        ICard(int rank, std::string suit) : rank_(rank), suit_(std::move(suit)) {};

        [[nodiscard]] virtual int getRank() const = 0;

        [[nodiscard]] virtual std::string getSuit() const  = 0;

        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ICard &c);

        bool operator>(const ICard &other) const;

        bool operator<(const ICard &other) const;

        bool operator<=(const ICard &other) const;

        bool operator>=(const ICard &other) const;

        bool operator==(const ICard &other) const;

        bool operator!=(const ICard &other) const;
    };

    class Card : public ICard {
    public:

        Card(int r, std::string s);

        [[nodiscard]] int getRank() const override;

        [[nodiscard]] std::string getSuit() const override;

    };
```

The `MockCard.h`

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
class MockCard : public ICard {
public:
    MockCard(int rank, std::string suit) : ICard(rank, std::move(suit)){};
    MOCK_METHOD(int, getRank, (), (const, override));
    MOCK_METHOD(std::string, getSuit, (), (const, override));
};
```

And  `CardCollection.h`:

```
    #include "Card.h"
    class CardCollection {

    protected:
        vector<ICard *> cards_;
    public:

        CardCollection() = default;

        ~CardCollection() = default;

        explicit CardCollection(vector<ICard*> cards);

        ICard* pop();

    ...
```

Here is my test:

```
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
TEST(CardCollectionTests, TestPop) {
    MockCard card1(6, "C");
    std::vector<ICard*> cards({&card1});
    CardCollection cc(cards);

    // pop the card off the collection, cast to MockCard
    auto* new_card = (MockCard*) cc.pop();

    ASSERT_EQ(6, new_card->getRank());
}
```

The best test that I can think of is to verify that the Card is a 6 of clubs. But we can't use the `Card` class directly as this would introduce unwanted dependencies into the unit test. So I resolve to cast the `ICard*` returned from `CardCollection::pop` to a `MockCard*` type so that we can use the `getRank()` method and test that the value returned is a `6`. However, this is a `MockCard` not a `Card` so `getRank()` actually returns a `0` and the test fails.

How can I set the value returned by `MockCard::getRank()` to `6`? More generally, Are there any obvious pitfalls you can see in my approach to testing this behavior and if so, what would you implement as an alternative?

Comment: You can use `ON_CALL(*new_card, getRank()).WillByDefault(Return(6));` to make that mock method return `6`

Comment: Excellant, thanks. If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: OK, I have posted it as an answer to your question

Comment: Also it's better and safe to use `dynamic_cast` to upcast/downcast rather than using typecasting. `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have acquired a pointer to `new_card`, you can use

```
ON_CALL(*new_card, getRank()).WillByDefault(Return(6));
```

to make your mock method return `6`